# Do certain cumulated dienes present geometric isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

Let's take, for example: 2,3-pentadiene.

Can't this compound present geometrical isomers, like 2-butene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properly speaking, these sorts of allenes/cumulated dienes do not exhibit geometric isomerism in the way that alkenes can. Rather, when each of the two respective carbons bear two different substituents, the molecule is [chiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_%28chemistry%29) and will exhibit enantiomerism. More specifically, these asymmetric allenes exhibit [axial chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_chirality). This is consequent to the two consecutive $\pi$-bonds being mutually perpendicular, which results in the molecule lacking any mirror plane of symmetry.

Generally, an even number of successive double bonds in a [cumulene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulene) produces a potential axis of chirality (again, assuming each carbon at the end of the double-bond system bears two different substituents), while an odd number results in the substituents at the ends of the double-bond system being coplanar, which permits geometric isomerism akin to that seen in alkenes.